# Overvoltage protection using opamp

Tags: operational-amplifier, comparator, over-voltage-protection

This circuit is used for overvoltage protection, I can see that the two opamp are comparators that will output 0 or 5V depending on the input, but can't see how it is protecting from overvoltage. Thank you for your help.

[image]

Comment: If this works, it depends very much on the internal design of the op-amp and unspecified behavior. And on the incoming signal not having enough energy to just blow up the op-amps. It might be very clever and work perfectly for some particular application. Or it might be nonsense. The best way to figure out which would be to test it with the particular over-voltage scenarios you need to protect against.

Answer (score 2):

Notice the 75 ohm BNC connector. It is likely weak AF to RF signals with not much drive current. If D1 and D2 are 1N4148 then response time is nanoseconds, and they prevent the 75 ohm line from seeing the capacitive load of the comparators outputs. The upper comparator clamps any negative voltage, while the lower comparator clamps if voltage is greater than 5.0 volts.

This bi-directional voltage clamp is fast to respond with little capacitive loading of the signal line. It makes sure down-stream devices do not get voltage peaks < zero volts or > 5 volts.

Note that this part number is a 20 MHZ quad op-amp with a 11V / uS slew rate, so it cannot protect pulses faster than a few MHZ. Maybe not very good clamp if frequency is over 100 KHZ.

Answer (score 1):

Assume a series resistor to the input, otherwise this all makes no sense.

If you apply a voltage to the resistor greater than +5 or less than 0V, an op-amp will come out of saturation and try to maintain the voltage at the input/output at 5V or 0V respectively. It's **not** acting as comparator under those conditions, it's acting as a **closed-loop amplifier**.

Below shows the two active modes in operation with a R-R amplifier.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fY43km.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Not all op-amps come out of saturation (and slew 5V) all that quickly, this particular one may operate faster because it has a shut-down mode. Ignoring the time to come out of saturation, it will take almost 500ns to slew to the correct voltage, so if you are trying to keep the voltage from going more than, say, 250mV out of range, it had better not be changing any faster than 0.5V/us.

The inputs of this kind of R-R amplifier can be expected to work okay a few hundred mV beyond the rails, and this particular amplifier is guaranteed to have **no phase reversal** so even if it spikes outside that range it should recover.

Comment: What is an R-R amplifier?

Comment: R-R is rail-to-rail, which can refer to inputs or outputs. This particular op-amp is RRIO (rail-to-rail inputs and outputs) which means it functions with inputs anywhere within the supply voltage range and the output will swing almost from one supply rail to the other when lightly loaded.

Comment: Oh! Of course, just me being dumb.

Comment: @SimonFitch I always figure that for every question regarding something that isn’t clear there are 10 or 100 folks who don’t ask, for whatever reason.

Comment: Well, thanks, for the quick reply, concise and complete as your replies usually are.